# Is there a way to exclude specific files from code review obligation on Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

I have the following configuration on my branch on azure devops:

[image]

Sometimes I need to change some binary files (not readable) on my repos and it takes time from my team to just approve the pull request.

I want to exclude this obligation when I'm changing just these binary files. These files are related to my app's documentation and all of them have the same file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't, you could move those files into a  new repo and not apply branch policies to that new repo. Then turn that repo into a package(NuGet, NPM, Maven, etc). So you can easily reference those binaries.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to exclude specific files from code review obligation on Azure Devops?

Indeed, there is no way to simply exclude source controlled files from Code Review.

To resolve this issue, the best way is **create a new branch based on your current branch**. And then change these binary files in the newly create branch.

When you complete your modification or you need code review, you can create a PR to merge the newly created branch into your current branch, and the Branch policies of the current branch will work.

This will avoid frequent code reviews during the time you modify the binary files, and also protect your current branch before you have completely completed your modifications and verification.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Leo, could you explain what is the `path filter` in a `build policy` is for? (`*;!*.md;!*.pdf`)